# Tooltip Twitter Number of Followers

Tags: jquery, wordpress, twitter, tooltip

I've got the tool tip to show the number of Twitter followers but it currently just shows the number of followers e.g 84, I'm wanting to get it to display as e.g. 84 Followers. Any help or suggestions would be great. (The OptionTree is just a wordpress plugin getting the Twitter username)

Here is my coding

```
$.ajax({
            url: 'http://api.twitter.com/1/users/show.json',
            data: {screen_name: '<?php get_option_tree( 'twitter_ss', '', 'true' ); ?>'},
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            success: function(data) {
                $('#twitter')
                .attr('title', data.followers_count,)
                .colorTip()
                }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$.ajax({
            url: 'http://api.twitter.com/1/users/show.json',
            data: {screen_name: '<?php get_option_tree( 'twitter_ss', '', 'true' ); ?>'},
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            success: function(data) {
                $('#twitter')
                .attr('title', data.followers_count + " Followers",)
                .colorTip()
                }
        });
```

Comment: Works a treat, Thank you Nick!

Comment: @Adam Wadsworth, if this is a correct answer, then you can approve it and take this question out of the unanswered queue.